# How to remove "Joomla! 2.5 Support Is Ending On December 31, 2014!" from admin panel?

Tags: joomla-2.5

I want to remove this message from my admin panel:

> Joomla! 2.5 Support Is Ending On December 31, 2014! Click Here for More Information.

[image: Joomla! 2.5 Support Is Ending On December 31, 2014!]

The message appeared after updating to the 2.5.28 version. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message is rendered by a plugin called "End of Support Notifier". The type of this plugin is "QuickIcon". To remove it go to "Extensions" -> "Plug-in Manager". Find and disable it.

[image: Disable this plugin!]